# How can I export webform analysis data to excel sheet?

Tags: 7, webforms, importing-exporting

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Problem:**
I want to export all `Analysis` datas to `excel sheet`.

I am using drupal `7.53` and `webform 7.x-4.14`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a module for this. You can find it here: [drupal.org/project/webform_analysis_export](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_analysis_export)